# Multiple/Batch increase of length and decrease of speed

Tags: video-editor

I have about 100 clips that I need to manually decrease the playback rate and increase the length of each clip. Usually I would add slow down each clip by 20% thus increasing the length by 20%.

I'm doing it now manually in Sony Vegas (not pro).

Is there any way of doing it automatically for 100 clips, and not for each one of them manually. Please feel free to propose some other software than Vegas, if Vegas cannot do this.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome! [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) is the typical go-to tool for automated workflows. But that depends on your comfort with command line tools. It also isn't exactly clear if you want a fully automated workflow or if you just want a simpler way to individually apply settings.

Comment: Thank you, I would like to be able for example to increase the length of all clips in a folder, by 20%. I'm ready to code a bit if needed. I'm more than comfortable with the command line tools.

Comment: Then FFmpeg should fit the bill. Unfortunately, I don't have a specific example for you to follow, but someone else might.